text input box can't receive pasted content
I am trying to make a text input box for a project i've been working on using pygame, I searched for various tutorials to help me make one but every single tutorial i found so far had the same issue, which is that you cannot paste any text (If you try to use ctrl + v it just pops up as a questionmark symbol in a box) so what could i do to fix this issue?
this is the code from my project summed up
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 500
height = 600

background = 255, 255, 255

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Consolas', 30)
text = ""
input_active = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True

while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    screen.fill((background))

    text_surf = font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text_surf, (10, 10))

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            input_active = True
            text = ""
        elif e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and input_active:
            if e.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                input_active = False
                data = text
            elif e.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                text = text[:-1]
            else:
                text += e.unicode

    pygame.display.flip()


you may need to write own function which check ctrl+v and it uses modules like paparclip to get data from clipboard. Or if I'm not wrong pygame has function to get content from clipboard

You have to check event for Ctrl+V and use pygame.scrap.get(...) to get data from clipboard.
Something like this:
if (e.key == pygame.K_v) and (pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL):
    #content = pygame.scrap.get('text/plain;charset=utf-8')
    #content = pygame.scrap.get('text/plain')
    content = pygame.scrap.get(pygame.SCRAP_TEXT)
    if content:
        text += content

See more in doc for pygame.scrap

There is module pygame.examples and you can run example scrap_clipboard for test.
python -m pygame.examples.scrap_clipboard

And here is source code

I found that some examples show get() with pygame.SCRAP_TEXT which  has value text/plain but when I use pygame.scrap.get_types() (on Linux) then it shows me type text/plain;charset=utf-8 and I have to check both

Finally I added this all to your code:
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.scrap.init()   # clipboard needs it
#pygame.scrap.set_mode(pygame.SCRAP_CLIPBOARD)  # standard clipboad
#pygame.scrap.set_mode(pygame.SCRAP_SELECTION)  # special clipboad on Linux

width = 500
height = 600

background = 255, 255, 255

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Consolas', 30)
text = ""
input_active = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True

while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    screen.fill((background))

    text_surf = font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text_surf, (10, 10))

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            input_active = True
            text = ""
        elif e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and input_active:
            if e.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                input_active = False
                data = text
            elif e.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                text = text[:-1]                
            elif e.key == pygame.K_v and (pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL):
                print('[DEBUG] pygame.SCRAP_TEXT:', pygame.SCRAP_TEXT)
                for t in pygame.scrap.get_types():
                    print('[DEBUG] type:', t)
                    
                content = pygame.scrap.get(pygame.SCRAP_TEXT)
                if not content:
                    content = pygame.scrap.get('text/plain;charset=utf-8')
                    if content:
                        content = content.decode('utf-8')

                if content:                
                    print(content)
                    text += content
                else:
                    print('[DEBUG] empty clipboard', content)
            else:
                text += e.unicode

    pygame.display.flip()

